# Android Facebook Sdk example : Error

Tags: android

I am working on Integrating Facebook in an android app.. I downloaded the examples from github. There was one simple example. I created an APP_ID and passed it in the activity. The problem is : when i login using one Facebook user account I was able to post on wall,upload photo. But when i logged out from one user account and logged in as another user I am able to just post text on the wall and not able to post photo. During the second user login m getting a Note like : "logging in will not add this app's activity to facebook" . Please help to resolve this. Does this mean that the previous user is not logged out properly. What might be wrong. Pls help me As soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Don't use native apps with something that is internet based, even Youtube are bailing on their native app, concentrate on HTML5 and jQuery Mobile and stop wasting you time!Facebook will bail on the native world soon too!

I know that's not the answer and I'm sure you need to get to the bottom of your problem, but iv'e being going nuts with apps and dynamic internet stuff for a while now and they just don't mix.

Apps offline and mobile websites online, its the only way forward!

Cheers,

Mike.